# Change Paste Special Settings using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to use Paste Special to change cell formatting for range Patrow as seen beneath. I have written some code found on the web but it does not change anything when I run it. Can anyone see why?

[image]

```
Sub PatPasteSpecial()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    myFile = "PAT Extract"

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like myFile & "*" Then
           Set PAT = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    PAT.EnableConnections
    
    'Counting last row and last column of the Daily Shout File (for copy and paste purposes)
    LastRow = PAT.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = PAT.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    LastRowColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1)
    
    Set Patrow = PAT.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:" & LastRowColumnLetter & LastRow)
    Set Dest = PAT.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
       
    Patrow.Copy
    Dest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
     
    
End Sub
```

Comment: IIRC, the destination range has to be the same size as the paste source range.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - not if it's a single cell.

Comment: What are your expectation from the above code? If you want doubling the range cells value you should use `Dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd`

Comment: My expectations are that the Paste changes to Values, Operation to Add. Currently defaulted at All & None, even after I run this procedure.

Comment: Did you change `xlAdd` with `xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: For more context, here's my issue... I'm conducting a VLookup between workbooks. This VLookup returns #N/A whenever I run it, but when I manually format cells with Paste to Values, and Operation to Add, it returns the correct value. I'm therefore looking for a way to format these using just VBA.

Comment: Could you share the name of the workbook containing this code i.e is it a workbook containing the string `PAT Extract`?

Comment: PAT Extract End Jan 21. When I run this, it successfully copies and pastes the data from the desired worksheet - it's just that the formatting settings do not change.

Comment: Then you should refer to it with [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) avoiding `myFile` and the `For Each...Next` loop: `Dim PAT As Workbook: Set PAT = ThisWorkbook`. Also, you might benefit from using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of each module.

Comment: Could you share the contents of e.g. `A2, A3, B2, B3` and the contents that you expect as a result after the code has run?

Comment: The PAT workbook is not ThisWorkbook - I'm running the macros on a different workbook. The contents of A2, B2, etc are the same for me.. when I go to Excel and select 'Paste Special', I expect to see the cells formatted like seen in the photo attached above. Instead, I'm seeing All & None checked. My macro intends to change this to Values & Add. Does this make sense?

Comment: Surely not. Do you know that your code is copying the same range that is being pasted and in the same worksheet and the same workbook, hence doubling the values in it? Maybe you want to copy/paste to another workbook, worksheet, or another range, I don't get it.

Comment: The dialog from your screenshot doesn't show how cells are formatted, it shows how they will be formatted after you press OK. Its default values are `All` and `None`.